# Swap column values in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I was reading the documentation of Pandas and i have a question. They say

> pandas aligns all AXES when setting Series and DataFrame from .loc, and .iloc.
>
> This will not modify df because the column alignment is before value assignment.

```
df.loc[:, ['B', 'A']] = df[['A', 'B']]
```

> It doesn't work like that. But it does if you do something like :
>
> ```
> df[['B', 'A']] = df[['A', 'B']]
> ```
>
> The correct way to swap column values is by using raw values:

```
df.loc[:, ['B', 'A']] = df[['A', 'B']].to_numpy()
```

You can read it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-callable#basics) if you want more details.
Why this is happening? I cant understand "column alignment is before value assignment.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that when you are using loc, pandas makes sure that "A" on the right is aligned to "A" on the left to save the values in the correct column, even if the order on the right is not correct. *Alignement*, is the process of matching A to A and B to B, irrespective of the order that is provided. *Assignment* is the process of saving the data in the columns.

On the other side the `df[['A', 'B']] = ...` notation creates new columns, which happen to be existing in this case and are overwritten with the raw values that are provided on the right of the operand, in order. Thus the swap.

Comment: So that means that if i use `df[['B', 'A']] = df[['A', 'B']]`  then i tell the program to assign the columns imidiately without changing the order of the columns, whereas using loc, pandas tries to align the columns (A to A and B to B) so A changes to A and B to B with result, nothing to change ?

Comment: Try to replace 'B' with 'C' on the left of =. With loc you'll get NaN in C as there is no alignment possible, and A remains A. With `[]`, you will put A in C and B in A

Comment: I meant: `df.loc[:, ['C','A']] = df[['A', 'B']]` vs `df[['C','A']] = df[['A', 'B']]
`